# Navigate through Array using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am creating custom memory allocator in C but I have trouble with moving in my "mem" array using pointer which has been previously alocated in it. I need to move one index to the left so i can see if the block before the one I am trying to free is empty or not. But moving pointer does not work as I would like.
So how can I move  one index before pointer ?

```
int main()
{
    char mem[50];
    char *pointer;
    char *ptr_toFree;

    pointer=(char *) &(mem[10]);
    pointer = "hello";
    int num = 10;
    mem[9] = num;

    ptr_toFree=(char*)(pointer-1);
    printf("Value of mem[9] = %d\n", *ptr_toFree);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pointer` points to the first element of the static array `"hello"`. `pointer-1` has undefined behavior.

Comment: FWIW, `pointer=(char *) &(mem[10]);` is just a complicated way of writing `pointer = mem+10;`

Comment: Your program can be reduced to `printf("%d\n", "hello"[-1])`, which is clearly invalid.

Comment: `pointer="hello";`-> `strcpy(pointer,"hello");`

Comment: Well that is just for demonstration. Are you saying if I don't do pointer="hello"; it would work ?

Comment: It might work but the behavior would be undefined as you are using memory out of bound of array

Comment: Perhaps explain line by line what you expect the statement on each line to do.

Comment: @SamuelSagan Yes, without `pointer = "hello"`, `pointer` would still point to `mem[10]`, so `pointer - 1` would point to `mem[9]`. I'm not sure what all of your casts are for, though.

Comment: thanks guys when I don't do pointer = "hello" i works just fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom memory allocator, you will need to implement malloc,realloc/free etc, how you keep track of the memory allocations is up to you (generally some sort of fixed header just before the pointer returned to the caller), there isn't a 'standard', so you can't just subtract n bytes from a pointer and start digging.